# How to place transparent image over camera view in codename one

Tags: camera, codenameone

First of all, thanks to everything of codenameone.

I would like to customize camera view, simply overlaying PNG image on the full camera view screen.

Any way how to do it?

Here is code snippet.

```
Form mainForm = new Form();
ImageViewer iv = new ImageViewer();

mainForm.getToolbar().addMaterialCommandToRightBar("", 
    FontImage.MATERIAL_CAMERA_ALT, 4, (ev) -> {
        filePath = Capture.capturePhoto();
        setImage(filePath, iv);
});
```

I couldn't any view component of camera view, because `Capture.capturePhoto()` works automatically.

Or is there any way to build custom camera component in codename one?
I googled and got about PeerComponents, however don't know how to use it.
Just please provide some small sample code for me.
Best regards.

Comment: you can set png on layer of custom camera

Answer (score 2):

Currently `Capture.capturePhoto()` opens its own "window" over the app so you can't customize it.  In the future we will likely add a more flexible API to embed the camera into your UI, especially now that we have Z-layering (we can draw over top of native widgets).

If you need this functionality right now, you would need to write a native interface and make your own capture component.